# Save a big list of lists in python 3 to a binary file

Tags: python, list, file, binary

I have a big list of lists like this in Python 3:

```
array = [[262,231],[123,222],[237272,292]...]
```

I want to save this in binary in python
I tried this:

```
output = open("pratica3.dat", "wb")
inbytes = bytes(array)
output.write(inbytes)
```

But this gives an error:
`TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

And if I try to run through the list and save, this gives me annother error of out of range 256

Comment: `bytes` doesn't work on arbitrary data structures. Try `pickle`.

Comment: Why do you want it to be binary?  Could you use `json`?  `pickle`?  Is there any specific format?  e.g. the array contains sublists of length 2 that only hold integers?  In that case, you can probably get the most minimal file size using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `pickle`:

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(array, output) # converts array to binary and writes to output

array = pickle.load(output) # Reads the binary and converts back to list
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the array as binary file, you need to open a binary file using `open(filename, 'wb')`. Otherwise, only using `pickle.dump()` throws `TypeError: file must have 'write' attribute`.

So, the code looks like this.

```
import pickle as pk

#save as binary file
pk.dump(your_array, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with pickle it will work fine

```py
import pickle  # import pickle

fptr = open("filename", "wb")  # open file in write binary mode
pickle.dump(my_list, ftpt)  # dump list data into file 
fptr.close()  # close file pointer

fptr = open("filename", "rb")  # open file in read binary mode
test_list = pickle.load(fptr)  # read binary data from file and store in list
print(test_list)  # print the data
fptr.close()
```